# OpenFST install freezing at seemingly random times

Tags: speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3, openfst

I'm trying to follow this installation guide for Jasper https://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/installation/. However, when I try to run `sudo make install` in the openfst-1.3.4/ folder, the installation will start and get to a random point before seemingly freezing up and not progressing. I am attempting to install this on a pi3 b+. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openfst uses heavy C++ features and compilation requires a lot of memory. Possible workarounds:

1. If you run make -j, use just one job
2. Use clang to compile instead of gcc, clang is more resource-efficient
3. Free some memory by releasing video buffer on PI and so on.
4. Cross-compile (easiest thing).